# PostgreSQL how to create table for big numbers like 1.33E+09 -1.8E+09?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL and I need to create a table to accommodate a bunch of data that is in this format:

`1.33E+09   -1.8E+09    58  -1.9E+09    2.35E+10    2.49E+10    2.49E+10    3.35E+08 etc.`

How to deal with it? I am not surely populating the table with this and if I need to convert it in order to work with it... Any suggestions?

is that a BIGINT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct data type for data like this is `double precision` or `float`.

It is obvious from the data that high precision is not necessary, so `numeric` would not be appropriate (it takes more storage and makes computations much slower).

`float` is only a good choice if you really need as few significant digits as your examples suggest and storage space is at a premium.

Your data are already in a format that PostgreSQL can accept for these data types, so there is no need for conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether you know the maximum range of data values your application might create.

A postgresql 'numeric' column will certainly hold any of the values you list above.  Per the docs: "up to 131072 digits before the decimal point; up to 16383 digits after the decimal point".

See the data type reference [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html).